# Function Input Issues With List of Lists

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to define a function that accepts as input a list of lists of integers, for example `[[2, 3], [45, 100, 2], [536], [103, 2, 8]]`. It should return a sorted version of the list, sorted by the sum of the integers in each sub-list so the return value would be `[[2, 3], [103, 2, 8], [45, 100, 2], [536]]`. I accomplished this with the code shown below, but this relies on getting user input instead of function input. Is there a way to accomplish this just based on function and not user input? Any help would be great!

```
user_list = raw_input("Please enter a list of integers: ")
input_list = user_list.split()
input_list = [eval(a) for a in input_list][0]

def sort_nested_lists(user_list):
    return sorted(user_list, key=sum)

print sort_nested_lists(user_list)
```

Comment: What you mean by function input here?

Comment: You've got a function (`sort_nested_lists()`) and it is getting an input (`user_list`).  So you've already got a function input.  Please try to rephrase what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am basically trying to eliminate my first line of code that asks the user for input, I am trying to insert this code into a larger file and do not want the prompt "Please enter a list of integers" to show up in terminal when its run. Hopefully that makes more sense.......

Comment: So where do you expect the list to come from??

Comment: Are you just trying to hard code a list?

Comment: Also, you probably want to pass `input_list`, not `user_list` on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Using the key=len argument in Python's sorted()

```
user_list = raw_input("Please enter a list of integers: ")
print sorted(user_list, key=len, reverse=False)
```

Eg.

```
user_list = [[1,2], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3], [1]]
Out: [[1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5]]
```